# javascript Date object converts local timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone

i have a model which have date propeties on it. i return this model from server as json object. server send this as json:

model.TaskName = "Task 1";

model.PlannedStartDate = "2015-08-26T15:31:00Z";

but in screen planned start date is 26.08.2015 18:31. when i check the model, javascript date object converts "2015-08-26T15:31:00Z" this date string into a new date object as "Wed Aug 26 2015 18:31:00 GMT+0300 (Turkey Daylight Time)".

i tried in console like :

-> new Date("2015-08-26T15:31:00Z")

<- Wed Aug 26 2015 18:31:00 GMT+0300 (Turkey Daylight Time)

i dont want Date object converts UTC date to local date. how can i do it?

Comment: I've removed the `json` tag. This has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 1):

It's not converting it to local time, it's that you're using `toString`, which *outputs* the date in local time. If you want the UTC time, use the `getUTCXyz` methods of `Date` to create your own string:

```js
var dt = new Date("2015-08-26T15:31:00Z");
snippet.log("UTC Hour: " + dt.getUTCHours());
snippet.log("UTC Min: " + dt.getUTCMinutes());
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

There's also `toUTCString`:

```js
var dt = new Date("2015-08-26T15:31:00Z");
snippet.log("UTC string: " + dt.toUTCString());
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```